# buttons not working index.html file

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I'm back. This time with working code that shows up in the body.
Another question to do with html of building this app.

As you can see, the picture below shows buttons that incorporate a picture which is not sized correctly. I'm wondering if the picture can be stretched to the button size, or the button size be reduced back to the picture size?
[image]

Here's the current code for the source code in Dreamweaver.

```
<div id="page" data-role="page" data-theme="no theme">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="no theme">
<div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" width="100%" height="100%"></div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="no theme">
<li class="accom"><a href="#accom" data-role="button" data-theme="none"><img src="images/accom_text.png"></a></li>
<li class="dining"><a href="#dining" data-role="button" data-theme="none"><img src="images/dining_text.png"></a></li>
<li class="events"><a href="#events" data-role="button" data-theme="none"><img src="images/events_text.png"></a></li>
<li class="maps"><a href="#maps" data-role="button" data-theme="none"><img src="images/maps_text.png"></a></li>
 <li class="attractions"><a href="#attractions" data-role="button" data-theme="none"><img src="images/attractions_text.png"></a></li>
<li class="transport"><a href="#transport" data-role="button" data-theme="none"><img src="images/transport_text.png"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" ><h4>copyright xyz</h4></div>
</div>
```

Where, the li class's corresponding to each page where li class="accom" etc, and the img src="images/name_notext.png"/> corresponding to the picture that's stuck in the top left.

Any help would be great.

Cheers.

CSS Code is as follows (the main I've used):

```
body {
    background-color:#42A5F5;
}
.ui-footer .ui-title {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
h3, h4 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
h3 + p, h4 + p {
    margin-top: 0;  
}

#accom {
    background-image:url
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#dining {
    background-image:url
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#events {
    background-image:url
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#maps {
    background-image:url(../images/sydneyregion.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#attractions {
    background-image:url
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}

#transport {
    background-image:url
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

li.accom {
    background-image:url(../images/accom_notext.png);   
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

li.dining {
    background-image:url(../images/dining_notext.png);  
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

li.events {
    background-image:url(../images/events_notext.png);  
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}   


li.maps {
    background-image:url(../images/maps_notext.png);    
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}   

li.attractions {
    background-image:url(../images/attractions_notext.png); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}   

li.transport {
    background-image:url(../images/transport_notext.png);   
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

The #maps etc don't have a background image yet due to other partners working on this with me (with lesser knowledge of this side).
li.accom sets each of the pictures out and to not repeat

## maps etc sets a background image for each page.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say the problem is likely in your css. Posting that would almost certainly help.

Comment: @ketan code has been updated above. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax code has been updated above. Thanks for your response.